# Chrome Extension value won't pass out of if-else statement

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome extension that will pass data from a webpage to a file and download it. Ultimately, the file ends up in Obsidian for easy note-taking. The extension works fine most of the time, as long as all the fields exist, so I've started introducing some code for when those elements don't exist.

For example, this is the original code:

```
const ogImage = document.querySelector('meta[property="og:image"]');
const og_image = ogImage.content;
```

That works fine until the `og:image` tag doesn't exist in the page. This is the code I came up with to handle the problem:

```
const ogImage = document.querySelector('meta[property="og:image"]');
if (ogImage != "") {
  const og_image = ogImage.content;
  console.log(og_image);
} else {
  const og_image = "https://---/vvMtZvn.jpg";
  console.log(og_image);
};
```

Depending on the page, the console will output the correct value. However, I get errors if I try to use the value outside of this code. The console in the following block replies with: `Uncaught ReferenceError: og_image is not defined`

```
const ogImage = document.querySelector('meta[property="og:image"]');
if (ogImage != "") {
  const og_image = ogImage.content;
} else {
  const og_image = "https://i.imgur.com/vvMtZvn.jpg";
};

console.log(og_image);
```

I've been searching but can't find an answer. Maybe I'm asking the wrong question. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Variables with keyword `const` are block scoped: [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

Comment: Unrelated (I think?) but comparing the results of a query selector to an empty string is counter-intuitive.

Comment: Replace all lines after the first one with `const og_image = ogImage?.content || "your-url";`

Comment: I'm mostly a hobby programmer, and that's probably giving myself too much credit, but I'm not sure why it would be counter-intuitive to compare the results of a query selector to an empty string. The `null` in the accepted answer below may be the better way, but it seems to me to be kind of the same thing. Is there a better way to check if the property exists?

Comment: @wOxxOm - I tried your suggestion and it works perfectly as well with much less code. I've decided to go with your suggestion, but not sure how to show that as the accepted answer since it's in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this.

```js
    let og_image;
    const ogImage = document.querySelector('meta[property="og:image"]');

    if (ogImage != null) {
      og_image = ogImage.content;
      console.log(og_image);
    } else {
      og_image = "https://---/vvMtZvn.jpg";
      console.log(og_image);
    };
```